# Django - Annotate with count across ManytoMany relationships

Tags: django, django-models, django-annotate

I am not able to find the way to annotate a queryset with a count of how many times an element is used in a many-to-many relationship.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    [...]
    # Profile can have multiple roles
    roles = models.ManyToManyField('Role', blank=True)
    [...]

class Role(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=300)
    [...]
```

For example I would have 5 roles:

- Role1
- Role2
- Role3
- Role4
- Role5

And 2 profiles with following roles assigned:

- Profile1

  - Role 1
  - Role 2
- Profile2

  - Role 1
  - Role 3
  - Role 4

I want to query the Role model and annotate with the number of profile that have that role.

So return a queryset like

```
Role1: company, name, description, profile_count=2
Role2: company, name, description, profile_count=1
```

etc...

I have tried that but it does not work:

```
Role.objects.annotate(profile_count=Count('profile__roles'))
```

It seems to return an overall count and not a count per role.

Any idea if that can be done natively in Django or if a raw SQL request is necessary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you just want this:

```
Role.objects.annotate(profile_count=Count('profile'))
```

Which is almost what you wrote.

Comment: Thanks for that! I guess I was overcomplicating things! After reading your response I realized that a ManyToMany relationship is both way and if I had declared it in the Role model instead of the Profile one, then I could have visualised the answer more easily. Anyway thanks for the quick answer, I spent way too much time on this! :)